# How can I customize UILocalNotification? XCode iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

how can i customize `UILocalNotification` so it can take two integers variables. I tried to inherit the `UILocalNotificaion` to a class but it crashes when i access one of the two integers that i have added.

```
@interface AHNotification : UILocalNotification {
    @public
    int AllIndex;
    int Index;
}
@property int AllIndex;
@property int Index;
@end


@implementation AHNotification
@synthesize AllIndex,Index;

-(AHNotification*) init{
    [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in userInfo property of UILocalNotification.

For example, you can store an NSDictionary of key-value pairs in it. Use NSNumber objects to represent your ints.